# Java CEF browser only loading when tab is selected

Tags: java, jtabbedpane, chromium-embedded

I am trying to create a browser on each tab using CEF, but I am finding that the content will only load once a tab is selected. Is the any way of getting the content of the tab to load in the background without the tab being selected.

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Application extends JFrame {

String[] testUrls = {"http://bbc.co.uk","http://reddit.com"};
private Collection<BrowserThread> browserThreads;

public Application(){

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    browserThreads = new ArrayList<BrowserThread>();
    TabManager tabManager = new TabManager();

    for (String u : testUrls){
        BrowserThread bt = new BrowserThread(u);
        bt.run();
        tabManager.add(u,bt.getUI());
        browserThreads.add(bt);

    }

    getContentPane().add(tabManager.getTabbedPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
    setSize(400,400);
    setLocationByPlatform(true);
    setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    setVisible(true);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            dispose();
            for(BrowserThread brt : browserThreads){
                brt.destroy();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void run(){}
public static void main(String[] args){
    final Application app = new Application();
    }
}
```

Next class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TabManager {

    JTabbedPane tabs = null;

    public TabManager(){
        tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    }

    public void add(String name, Component browser){
        tabs.addTab(name,browser);
    }
    public JTabbedPane getTabbedPane(){
        return tabs;
    }

}
```

Next class

```
import org.cef.CefApp;
import java.awt.*;

public class BrowserThread implements Runnable {

    private CefApp cefApp_;
    private String url;
    private Component ui;

    public BrowserThread(String url){
        this.cefApp_ = CefApp.getInstance();
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void run(){
        ui = cefApp_.createClient().createBrowser(url,false,false).getUIComponent();
    }

    public Component getUI(){
        return ui;

    }
    public void destroy(){
        cefApp_.dispose();
    }
}
```